# split lines in Makefile functions

Tags: makefile

I define function in my Makefile (here `clone_or_pull`) it's working well

I would like to know what is the correct way to slip lines in the function body, to get 80cols lines.

Here is my `Makefile`

```
#
# Development workflow
#
define clone_or_pull
        ([ -d $(1) ] && ((cd $(1) && git fetch && git rebase) || printf '\e[91mCould not rebase git repo $(1)\e[0m\n')) || git clone git@gitlab.com:group1/$(1).git
endef

clone_or_pull_dependencies:
        $(call clone_or_pull,zf_nlp)
        $(call clone_or_pull,nlp_api)
```

I call it with:

```
$ make clone_or_pull_dependencies
```

Comment: Try \ at the line's end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @igagis \ at the end made the trick.
BTW it then else make it more clear.

```
define clone_or_pull
  if test -d $(1) ;                                                    \
  then                                                                 \
    cd $(1) && git fetch && git rebase ;                               \
  else                                                                 \
    printf '\e[91mCould not rebase git repo $(1); Cloning it\e[0m\n' ; \
    git clone git@gitlab.com:group1/$(1).git ;           \
  fi
  @printf '\e[92m Update of $(1) Done\e[0m\n'
endef
```